# Uncaught Error after migration to Material-UI v4

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am stuck with the following error after migrating from Material-UI v3 to v4. The project compiles successfully, but this error is shown at runtime when inspecting the browser console. Nothing renders, there is just a white screen and this error on the console.

```
Uncaught Error: You are calling withTheme(Component) with an undefined component.
You may have forgotten to import it.
    at withTheme (withTheme.js:14)
    at Module../node_modules/material-ui-pickers/dist/material-ui-pickers.esm.js (material-ui-pickers.esm.js:3661)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:724)
    at fn (bootstrap:101)
    at Object../node_modules/@jsonforms/material-renderers/lib/controls/MaterialDateControl.js (MaterialDateControl.js:63)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:724)
    at fn (bootstrap:101)
    at Object../node_modules/@jsonforms/material-renderers/lib/controls/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:724)
    at fn (bootstrap:101)
```

Updated packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.1.1",   // old version: 3.1.1
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.0",  // old version: 3.0.1
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.3.3", // new
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",           // old version: 1.29.0
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",           // removed, according to migration guide, it's nt needed anymore.
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you migrate from v2 or v3?

Comment: umm, noo... Omg, I can't understand what is wrong with my question so I'm getting down votes.. :x

Comment: don't mind the down votes, people are down voting because they think this question has missing information, but it's probably migration problem and not problem in your code. To clarify that, write in the question that withTheme doesn't exist in your code

Comment: what version did you migrate from?

Comment: From v3 to v4, I have written that in first post. :)

Comment: did you update @material-ui/styles to "^4.0.0"?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to include versions, re-check the first post.

Comment: Please show the entire package.json, not just the updated packages. The error indicates you are using `@jsonforms/material-renderers` which is dependent on `material-ui-pickers`. This older version of `material-ui-pickers` is incompatible with v4 of material-ui. If you update to the latest version of `@jsonforms/material-renderers` it will pull in a compatible version of [@material-ui/pickers](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jsonforms/blob/master/packages/material/package.json#L52), though you should also update Material-UI to at least 4.3.

Comment: @RyanCogswell that was exactly the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems like the component that you are passing to the `withTheme` function is either non-existant, you reference it before creation, you forgot to import the component that you will pass on later to the `withTheme` or you have a spelling mistake.

Check in the file in which you are calling the function `withTheme` and double check if in that file what you are passing on is defined...

This is as much as I can help without watching the code in which `withTheme` is called

Comment: The problem is that 'withTheme' exists nowhere in the code. The only place which appears is the one of node_modules dist folder as you can see from error.

Comment: @IliyanIvanov You don't need to do anything like what is specified in https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#styles

Comment: I have followed that guide of course and then I came up with that error. Also tried to delete whole node_module folder and run npm install over again to make sure everything is at the specified version in package.json.

Comment: @IliyanIvanov Have you deleted the `package-lock.json` also after deleting `node_modules`? Sometimes the `package-lock` is causing issues

Comment: Nope.. but I think I found the problem, tried to update @jsonforms/material-renderers and this error is gone, but now fighting with other errors.. :D

Answer (score -1):

As seen from the error, you are probably using material-ui-pickers. 
This library migrated to [@material-ui/pickers](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers) 
That's probably why you are getting the error. 
Try to remove material-ui-pickers from your package.json, and install the new library. 
Also, follow the [migration guide](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/upgrading-to-v3)

Comment: I don't have such a library in package.json. Also, let's repeat I'm not migrating to v3, I'm migration to v4!

Comment: @IliyanIvanov be patient, i'm trying to help you. I know you are migrating material-ui/core to v4. the migration guide i posted is for a different library - material-ui/pickers (the latest version there is v3). However, ignore it if you don't have material-ui-pickers

Comment: Ohh I didn't notice that's complete different library, but I don't have such package. I guess that's an inner dependency of @material-ui/core